# what is different bitmap compress option in Android webview

Tags: android, webview, compression

when I upload my captured webveiw(bitmap image), I use this :

```
public static void saveBitmaptoPng(Bitmap bitmap, String folder, String name) {
    String ex_storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    // Get Absolute Path in External Sdcard
    String foler_name = "/" + folder + "/";
    String file_name = name + ".png";
    String string_path = ex_storage + foler_name;

    File file_path;
    try {
        file_path = new File(string_path);
        if (!file_path.isDirectory()) {
            file_path.mkdirs();
        }
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(string_path + file_name);

        **bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);**
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        Log.e("FileNotFoundException", exception.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        Log.e("IOException", exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It is working well. but when I change 90 to 100 of Bitmap.CompressFormat,

I got an error whe getresponseCode

```
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (serverResponseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            } else {
                is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getErrorStream());
                return null;
            }
```

when changing from 90 to 100, process flow errorStream.... but I don't know any reasons....  even 95 is also not working well..

Comment: connection.getErrorStream() is called if it received error code not in 2xx range. Normally, the bitmap function should do nothing with your http request. They should be understood respectively. Please try to send http request using browser plugin.

Comment: @LongRanger hm.. whan you mean is the bitmap function is not relation with url connection. right?  but I just change the quality from 100 to 90, and don't handle other things. but working well...  so I'm confused...

Comment: and what is http request using browser plugin...?

Comment: Try to send the httprequest using some browser plugin like Postman.Try to change the parameter of the request to check whether the response is successful

Comment: ok! Thanks, I'll try postman. Is it related on the http request plugin??

Comment: yes, Because getting the errorstream should be called if it received the status not in 2xx range, which means there is some error in your request or error in server. Therefore, you should check the http request call with your parameter first. Bitmap quality should not be the root cause of your exception.

Comment: hm.... but when I change bitmap quality  from 100 to 90 (I changed just this one number), It is working well.... got 2xx and when changing 90 to 100, I got 500 request code... even I don't change other things... hm...I can't find the reason...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121801/discussion-between-long-ranger-and-adrian).